# Registry Check CMD

Tags: cmd

How can I found only the registry **VALUE NAME** in this code (Windows 7 Home Premium)

```
REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ProductName
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help with the find filter:

```
REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ProductName |find /i "value name"
```

Comment: It works but, I will show the **ProductName**  without the registry key

Comment: The solution does what you asked.  Improve your question to show details and what you expect to get from the registry.